# Restore linux partition table of one raid0 drive after accidentally installing windows over it

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, software-raid

**How the problem arrose:**
So I made a very stupid mistake yesterday. I installed windows 10 on the wrong harddrive (I didn't expect the installation to start right after choosing the drive). After realizing what happened I immediately turned off the computer. The progress of copying files still said 0%, but I have no idea how reliable that is. Anyway the partitions got overwritten with the ones from windows. To make it a bit more interesting, it was a luks-encrypted software raid **EDIT**<strike>(RAID 5: striped array with distributed parity information)</strike> RAID 0 (sorry for the confusion, I'm still learning about raids, I mean a raid optimized for performance not redundancy, see output of mdadm below) with ubuntu.

**What I tried so far**:
I've been searching for a solution for a day now. Trying to follow the instructions on

https://www.tecmint.com/install-testdisk-data-recovery-tool-in-linux/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Off course I only have a partial backup.

I wasn't able to recover the linux partitions with TestDisk.

**Information I gathered**:
This is the output of sudo testdisk -list (I left out my other harddrives)

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 960 GB / 894 GiB - CHS 915715 64 32
     Partition          Start        End    Size in sectors
 1 P Windows Recovery Env        2048    1085439    1083392 [Basic data partition]
 2 P EFI System               1085440    1288191     202752 [EFI system partition]
 3 P MS Reserved              1288192    1320959      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
 4 P MS Data                  1320960 1875384319 1874063360 [Basic data partition]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096

Disk /dev/nvme1n1 - 960 GB / 894 GiB - CHS 915715 64 32
     Partition          Start        End    Size in sectors
 1 P EFI System                  2048    1050623    1048576
 2 P Linux filesys. data      1050624    3147775    2097152
 3 P Linux filesys. data      3147776 1875382271 1872234496
```

$sudo gpart  /dev/nvme0n1:

```
Begin scan...
Possible partition(Windows NT/W2K FS), size(529mb), offset(1mb)
Possible partition(DOS FAT), size(99mb), offset(530mb)
Possible partition(Windows NT/W2K FS), size(915070mb), offset(645mb)
End scan.

Checking partitions...

* Warning: partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX) starts beyond disk end.

* Warning: partition(DOS or Windows 95 with 32 bit FAT, LBA) starts beyond disk end.

* Warning: partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX) starts beyond disk end.
Partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX): invalid primary 
Partition(DOS or Windows 95 with 32 bit FAT, LBA): invalid primary 
Partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX): invalid primary 
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

**EDIT**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/0 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0 
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 1

              Name : ubuntu-server:0
              UUID : 9e05e8de:c64651b3:3c4c0142:df1a539d
            Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -     259       11        -        /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

**My main question**:
nvme0n1 is the overwritten disk, the partition should be more or less identical like on the intact nvme1n1. Is it maybe possible to manually recreate the partition?
The system is still booting, because the boot partion is on the intact nvme1n1, up to the point till it tries to mount the ubuntu partion.
I would very much appreciate an experts opinion. **Is there any chance of recovery or should I forget about it?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can confidently say you haven't screwed yourself yet.

You should be able to recover from the lone intact disk. Get into a live environment, e.g. the Ubuntu Install disk 'trial mode'. Then you should be able to mount the LUKS disk, then remount the LVM RAID 5 inside of it.

See here for some sample instructions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445652/

The developer email list archives also have some tips on other recovery methods. https://marc.info/?l=dm-crypt&w=2&r=1&s=raid5&q=b. You can also use the mailing list for more help "dm-crypt@saout.de"

Comment: Thank you. I think I confused raid 0, which i seem to have, with raid 5. I will gladly make use of the mailing list you suggested and edited my question.

Comment: If you have raid 0, then you are probably screwed. Sorry.